# Typing indicator with action cable in rails- 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable, hotwire-rails, turbo

I am unable to add typing indicator in my rails app with action cable I have created app in rails 7 and I user trubo stream tag and broadcast in it so I did't used channel for live chat , I tried to find tutorial and video but there is not any

I want to add typing indicator so I writtern js for the same on input it will called and it will go to controller
On input I am calling controller "rtm"

room controller

```
  def rtm 
    @typing = "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"
    # ActionCable.server.broadcast "typing_channel",{ message: "helloo"}
    # @typings.broadcast_append_to "typing"
    Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_append_to "typing", target: 'typing', partial: 'rooms/typing', locals: { message: "@typing" }
  end
```

here I have issue how can I broadcast the typing message to my room page

Room.rb

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
    scope :public_rooms, -> { where(is_private: false) }
    has_many :messages
    after_create_commit {broadcast_append_to "rooms"}
end
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
  after_create_commit { broadcast_append_to self.room }
end
```

rooms/index

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tmo = null;
  $("#msg").on("input", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/rooms/rtm',
      data: {data: ''}
    });
    document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = "Typing...";
    if (tmo) {
      clearTimeout(tmo);
    }
    tmo = setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/rooms/rmm',
        data: {data: ''}
    });
      document.getElementById("typing").innerHTML = "";
    }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>

<div class="container">
  <h5> Hi <%= current_user&.firstname %> </h5>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> 

  <br>  <h4> Rooms </h4>
  <%= render partial: 'layouts/new_room_form' %>
  <%= turbo_stream_from "rooms" %>
<div id="rooms">
  <%= render @rooms %>
</div>
</div>

<% if @single_room.present? %>
<%= link_to @single_room.name,@single_room, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

  <%= turbo_stream_from @single_room %>
  <div id="messages">
    <%= render @messages %>
  </div>

  <%= render partial: 'layouts/new_message_form' %>

  <%=  @typing %>
  <%= turbo_stream_from @typing %>

  <div id="typing">
  </div>

  <%= render partial: 'rooms/typing' %>
  <span id="typing"></span><br>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typing_channel.js

```
import consumer from "channels/consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("TypingChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log("connected")

    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log(data)
    const box = document.getElementById('typing');
    if (box.textContent.includes(data.body)) {
    } else {
      $('#typing').append('<p>'+ data.body + data.message +'</p>');
    }
  }
});
```

I am using below js for indicator

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tmo = null;
  $("#chat").on("input", function(){
     $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/rooms/rtm',
    });
    if (tmo) {
      clearTimeout(tmo);
    }
    tmo = setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/rooms/rmm',
    });
    }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>
```

in controller

ActionCable.server.broadcast "typing_channel", {message: 'Typing', body: "#{current_user.email}"}

Comment: If still any one have issue comment here will help

Answer (score 1):

To get the typing indicator you need to use action cable and create a channel for it. You can use turbo stream to render the typing indicator. Example:

app/channels/typing_channel.rb

```
class TypingChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "typing_channel"
  end
end
```

app/javascript/channels/typing_channel.js

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("TypingChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});
```

app/views/rooms/index.html.erb

```
<div id="typing">
  <%= turbo_stream_from "typing_channel" %>
</div>
```

app/views/rooms/_typing.html.erb

```
<p><%= message %></p>
```

app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  def rtm
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "typing_channel", { message: "helloo" }
  end
end
```

app/javascript/controllers/rooms_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import consumer from "../channels/consumer"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "input" ]

  connect() {
    this.subscription = consumer.subscriptions.create("TypingChannel", {
      received: (data) => {
        this.renderTyping(data)
      }
    })
  }

  renderTyping(data) {
    const typing = document.getElementById("typing")
    typing.innerHTML = data.message
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

Is not possible to use turbo stream with action cable. You need to use action cable to get the typing indicator. You can use turbo stream to render the typing indicator.

Comment: I ma app I created live chat without channel,, I user turbo_stream_tag for acn broadcasting from model

Comment: I have added more info in my question

Comment: I don't have app/javascript/controllers/rooms_controller.js

I have to create manual and add your code that's it?

Comment: Also I am geting error like 
undefined local variable or method `message' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000021480>
Did you mean?

Comment: You have to create several other codes. That was just a good example.

Comment: I have some other problem with my channel it not showing connected in concole, I have user     stream_from "typing_channel"
and     console.log("connected.......?")
 but not showing

Comment: You have some problems. Try starting from the beginning. Watch that video I sent you and restart your project.

Comment: my channel is connected but with your code still no idea how I can show typing indicator